# Android image 1/3rd of the screen with scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, I download images from my web server (each having a different resolution) but I would like to show these images on a fragment screen consistently.

Ideally, I would like the image to have width="match_parent" and height to take 1/3 of the screen EXACTLY. Furthermore, the image should be shown in a  as it's part of a content layout with other controls that could possibly grow larger than the screen height (hence the need for scrolling).

I have tried putting the image and the rest of the content in a LinearLayout and then setting the weight to 1 (with max weight being 3), but since the image and the other contents are in a scrollview, it doesn't quite seem to work. the image is either too large or too small (depending on the orientation and the resolution of the image) and my 1/3rd settings don't seem to be respected.

Is there any way to do this other than fixing the height to a pre-determined (dp) value? I would like to avoid that unless there's no other choice.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always set the height for each of the images programatically to 1/3 the height of the screen, like so

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image); 

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) img.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = (int)height / 3;
    img.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. I'll try this tomorrow and will mark as an answer if it work (I don't see why it wouldn't).

Comment: great, hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry didn't get to test it until today. It works as expected. Cheers.